Can I repent one Salat al-Tawbah for multiple sins?
As-salamu alaykum,
I want to repent but I've come across multiple sins to ask forgiveness for. Should I repent once (Salat al-Tawbah) for all of the multiple sins, or should I repent and pray for each sin separately, meaning different individual prayers for each.
Also, how many times should I perform this salat and repent? Everyday, or for a couple of days?
